# Angular cli installation yields ssh error

Tags: node.js, ssh, angular-cli

Installing the angular cli with:

```
npm -g install angular/cli
```

Yields this error with node 8.6:

```
npm ERR! Error while executing:
npm ERR! /usr/bin/git ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/angular/cli.git
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Permission denied (publickey).
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! and the repository exists.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! exited with error code: 128

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/user/.npm/_logs/2017-10-10T16_41_49_141Z-debug.log
```

Changing to node version 6.11.4 yeilds similar errors:

```
npm ERR! git clone --template=/Users/user/.npm/_git-remotes/_templates --mirror git@github.com:angular/cli.git /Users/user/.npm/_git-remotes/git-github-com-angular-cli-git-05516032: Cloning into bare repository '/Users/user/.npm/_git-remotes/git-github-com-angular-cli-git-05516032'...
npm ERR! git clone --template=/Users/user/.npm/_git-remotes/_templates --mirror git@github.com:angular/cli.git /Users/user/.npm/_git-remotes/git-github-com-angular-cli-git-05516032: Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '64:ff9b::c01e:fd71' to the list of known hosts.
npm ERR! git clone --template=/Users/user/.npm/_git-remotes/_templates --mirror git@github.com:angular/cli.git /Users/user/.npm/_git-remotes/git-github-com-angular-cli-git-05516032: Permission denied (publickey).
npm ERR! git clone --template=/Users/user/.npm/_git-remotes/_templates --mirror git@github.com:angular/cli.git /Users/user/.npm/_git-remotes/git-github-com-angular-cli-git-05516032: fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR! git clone --template=/Users/user/.npm/_git-remotes/_templates --mirror git@github.com:angular/cli.git /Users/user/.npm/_git-remotes/git-github-com-angular-cli-git-05516032: 
npm ERR! git clone --template=/Users/user/.npm/_git-remotes/_templates --mirror git@github.com:angular/cli.git /Users/user/.npm/_git-remotes/git-github-com-angular-cli-git-05516032: Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! git clone --template=/Users/user/.npm/_git-remotes/_templates --mirror git@github.com:angular/cli.git /Users/user/.npm/_git-remotes/git-github-com-angular-cli-git-05516032: and the repository exists.
npm ERR! Darwin 16.7.0
npm ERR! argv "/Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.4/bin/node" "/Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.4/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "angular/cli"
npm ERR! node v6.11.4
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code 128

npm ERR! Command failed: git clone --template=/Users/user/.npm/_git-remotes/_templates --mirror git@github.com:angular/cli.git /Users/user/.npm/_git-remotes/git-github-com-angular-cli-git-05516032
npm ERR! Cloning into bare repository '/Users/user/.npm/_git-remotes/git-github-com-angular-cli-git-05516032'...
npm ERR! Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '64:ff9b::c01e:fd71' to the list of known hosts.
npm ERR! Permission denied (publickey).
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! and the repository exists.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/user/npm-debug.log
```

This is happening with both my Ubuntu remote server and my local MacBook, both of which have valid SSH keys added to my Github account.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It should be [`@angular/cli`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/cli) since `angular/cli` is a non existing npm-package:

`npm -g install @angular/cli`

Answer (score 0):

the right command is :
     npm install -g @angular/cli 
you can check this to can start your app :
https://angular.io/guide/quickstart